# Get a modules data without an entity statement in VHDL?

Tags: memory, module, entity, vhdl

I need to get some data from a module I was given, but I don't know if it is even possible or how to approach the problem.

Is it possible to get information from another module if that module doesn't have an entity map? It only has a generic with TIME statements.

Is it at all possible to get anything out of this module? 
It writes to a memory, could I pull things out of that?

This is the file I have.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;

use STD.TEXTIO.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_TEXTIO.all;

entity MIPS is
  generic (
    MEM_DLY : TIME := 0.5 ns;
    CYC_TIME: TIME := 2 ns
  );
end entity MIPS;

architecture MIPS of MIPS is

signal  PC : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 ) := X"0000_0010";
signal  READ_DATA2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 ) := ( others => '0');

signal HUH       : BIT_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
signal HUHINS    : STRING ( 1 to 25 );
signal INSTRUC   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
signal M_DATA_IN : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 ) := ( others => 'Z');
signal M_DATA_OUT : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 ):= ( others => 'Z');
signal M_ADDR    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 11 downto 0 ) := ( others => '0');
signal CLK       : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal MEMREAD   : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal M_DATA_WHEN   : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal MEMWRITE  : STD_LOGIC := '0';

signal CYCLE     : INTEGER := 1;

begin

CLOCK_PROC:
  process
  begin
    CLK <= '1';
    wait for CYC_TIME/2;
    CLK <= '0';
    wait for CYC_TIME/2;
    CYCLE <= CYCLE + 1;
  end process;

TEST_PC_PROC:
  process ( CLK ) is
  begin
    if RISING_EDGE ( CLK ) then
      PC <= PC + 4;
    end if;
  end process;



INSTR_MEM_PROC:
  process ( PC ) is                       -- make subject only to address
    type INSTR_STR_ARY is array ( 0 to 1023 ) of STRING ( 1 to 25 );
    variable MEMSTRR : INSTR_STR_ARY:=(others => "                         ");
    type MEMORY is array ( 0 to 1023 ) of BIT_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    variable MEM     : MEMORY := ( others => X"0000_0000");
    variable IADDR   : INTEGER;               -- integer for address
    variable DTEMP   : BIT_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    variable INIT    : INTEGER := 0;          -- when to initialize...
    file IN_FILE     : TEXT open READ_MODE is "instr_mem.txt";
    variable BUF     : LINE;
    variable ADR_STR : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    variable TADR    : INTEGER;
    variable TDATA   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    variable BDATA   : BIT_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    variable STR_ING : STRING ( 1 to 25 );
  begin
    if INIT = 0 then
      while not (ENDFILE ( IN_FILE )) loop
        READLINE ( IN_FILE, BUF );
        HREAD    ( BUF, ADR_STR ); -- get the address on the line
        TADR := CONV_INTEGER ( ADR_STR (14 downto 2));
        HREAD    ( BUF, TDATA   ); -- get the data on the line
        BDATA := To_bitvector (TDATA);
        MEM ( TADR ) := BDATA;     -- put into memory
        for J in 1 to 25 loop
          STR_ING(J) := ' ';
        end loop;
        READ     ( BUF, STR_ING ); -- get instruction string
        MEMSTRR ( TADR ) := STR_ING;
        report "iteration of loop";
      end loop;
      INIT := 1;                   -- when all data in, set INIT to 1;
    end if;                        -- end of INIT check
    IADDR := CONV_INTEGER ( PC ( 14 downto 2 ));
    HUH <= MEM ( IADDR );
    INSTRUC <= To_StdLogicVector ( MEM ( IADDR )) after MEM_DLY;
    HUHINS <= MEMSTRR ( IADDR );
    report "should hit  INSTRUC";
  end process;
M_DATA_IN_STMT:
  M_DATA_IN <= READ_DATA2 ;

-- The following is the magic process
-- User must supply:
--  M_ADDR - memory address (data memory) as a 12 bit STD_LOGIC_VECTOR
--           Remember the M_ADDR is a WORD address
--  M_DATA_IN - value going to memory from hardware (data path)
--           Remember that this is 32 bit STD_LOGIC_VECTOR, user supplied
--  READ_DATA2 - this is to be replaced by user's sourceof info for memory
DATA_MEMORY_PROCESS:                          -- name of process ...
  process ( M_ADDR, CLK, MEMREAD ) is         -- Sens: M_ADDR, CLK, MEMREAD
  file IN_FILE: TEXT open READ_MODE is "data_mem_init.txt"; -- initial data
  file OUT_FILE: TEXT open WRITE_MODE is "mem_trans.txt";   -- results
  variable BUF : LINE;                        -- declare BUF as LINE
  variable TVAL : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 ); -- var for temp value
  variable TADRHEX : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 ); -- var for address
  variable TADR : INTEGER;                    -- address as integer
  type MEM_TYPE is array ( 0 to 1023 ) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
  variable THE_MEMORY : MEM_TYPE := ( others => X"00000000" ); -- the memory
  variable FIRST : BOOLEAN := TRUE;           -- flag for first time thru
  constant STR : STRING ( 1 to 3 ) := "   ";  -- 3 spaces - for printing
  constant WR_STR : STRING ( 1 to 3 ) := "W  "; -- for write
  constant RD_STR : STRING ( 1 to 3 ) := "R  "; -- for read
  variable TSTR2 : STRING ( 1 to 29 );          -- to create a string
  type MEMSTR_TYPE is array ( 0 to 1023 ) of STRING ( 1 to 29 ); -- 
  variable INSTRS : MEMSTR_TYPE;
  begin                                       -- start here
    if FIRST then                             -- first time thru,
      while FIRST loop                        -- loop on data available - until
        if not ( ENDFILE ( IN_FILE )) then    -- end of file shows up
          READLINE(IN_FILE, BUF);             -- read a line from file,
          HREAD(BUF, TADRHEX);                -- get address from BUF
          TADR := CONV_INTEGER ( TADRHEX );   -- turn it into integer
          HREAD(BUF, TVAL);                   -- next, get value from BUF
          THE_MEMORY(TADR/4) := TVAL;         -- put TVAL into the memory
        else                                  -- the 'else' is for end of file
          FIRST := FALSE;                     -- EOF shows up - set FIRST false
        end if;
      end loop;                               -- where loop ends...
    end if;                                   -- where if FIRST ends ...
    if MEMREAD = '1' then                     -- now, memory function 'read'
      M_DATA_OUT <= THE_MEMORY ( CONV_INTEGER ( M_ADDR ) / 4 ); -- get val from
      M_DATA_WHEN <= not M_DATA_WHEN;         -- and invert M_DATA_WHEN
    else                                      -- if not MEMREAD,
      M_DATA_OUT <= ( others => 'Z' );        -- set memory out to 'Z's
    end if;
    if RISING_EDGE ( CLK ) then               -- on clock edge...
      if MEMREAD = '1' then                   -- if MEMREAD asserted,
        TADR := CONV_INTEGER ( M_ADDR ) / 4;  -- set TADR to address as int
        TVAL := THE_MEMORY ( TADR );          -- and get contents to TVAL
        WRITE (BUF, RD_STR);                  -- then build BUF; put read indi
        HWRITE (BUF, M_ADDR);                 -- and the address
        WRITE (BUF, STR);                     -- some spaces
        HWRITE (BUF, TVAL);                   -- and the value
        WRITE (BUF, STR);                     -- more spaces
    WRITE (BUF, NOW);                     -- current simulation time
        WRITELINE (OUT_FILE, BUF);            -- and send line to file.
      elsif MEMWRITE = '1' then               -- if not read, but it is write
        TADR := CONV_INTEGER ( M_ADDR ) / 4;  -- set TADR to address as int
        TVAL := M_DATA_IN;                    -- set TVAL as data in value
        WRITE (BUF, WR_STR);                  -- start buffer with write indi
        HWRITE (BUF, M_ADDR);                 -- then the address
        WRITE (BUF, STR);                     -- then some spaces
        HWRITE (BUF, TVAL);                   -- and the value written
        WRITE (BUF, STR);                     -- still more spaces
    WRITE (BUF, NOW);                     -- simulation time
        WRITELINE (OUT_FILE, BUF);            -- and send line to file
        THE_MEMORY ( CONV_INTEGER ( M_ADDR ) / 4) := M_DATA_IN;
                                              -- and finally, value to the mem
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

end architecture MIPS;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you presented simulates the memories that your MIPS processor will interact with - a program memory and a data memory.

Your MIPS will interact with the program memory by providing a value for PC; the corresponding instruction will be handed to your CPU on signal INSTRUCT. You'll probably delete the lines corresponding to the TEST_PC_PROC process, since the actual PC value will come from the MIPS. The program to be run by the CPU is given in file data_mem_init.txt. This program memory is asynchronous.

Your MIPS will interact with the data memory through signals M_ADDR, M_DATA_OUT, M_DATA_IN, and MEMREAD. To read data, your CPU will set M_ADDR and MEMREAD=1, and provide the address in M_ADDR. The given code will set M_DATA_OUT with the requested data. To write data, you will set M_DATA_IN or READ_DATA2 (or replace READ_DATA2 with a signal of your choice). The data will be written on the rising edge of CLK.

Don't be distracted by the WRITE/HWRITE calls, they just keep a log on file mem_trans.txt.

IMO, this interface is much more complicated than it needed to be. You're probably better or if you keep your MIPS implementation in totally separate files, and just add the signals needed to interact with this model to its ports list.

Comment: That explains a lot, thanks. 

Unfortunately I don't have the luxury of deleting or adding stuff to this file...  

So if I am understanding what you're saying correctly, I can interface with this modules signals directly from another module, like the top module?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you *are* supposed to edit this file. Look at the instructions for signal `READ_DATA2`: *"this is to be replaced by user's sourceof info for memory"*. The least instrusive way of using the file is just to instantiate your CPU in the architecture.

Comment: Another clue that you'll have to edit the module is that it assigns to PC in process TEST_PC_PROC. This is a task that will have to be replaced by your CPU, right?

Comment: That would make sense. The only thing that worries me is the professor that gave this to me, usually labels test benches as 'ATB' and I've never had to edit a module to add anything in. 
Thanks though, that would make the most sense. I just didn't think of it like that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question what you are hoping to achieve with this mystery module that you have... but here's some ideas which might trigger something:

If you have a `component` for the module in question, then you can instantiate it within your design and then manipulate its inputs to make its outputs do what they should.  Maybe it has some documentation to give you some clues!

If it writes to memory and you have a multi port memory controller within your system connected to the same memory, you could build something which will read data from the memory after your mystery module has written to it.

Or finally, if this is an FPGA, you can embed a logic analyser into the FPGA bitstream to observe the signals going to and from the secret module.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the VHDL file that I have.

I don't have a component, just generic. No in/out at all.
This is not implemented, just simulated. 

I don't know where to begin in building the memory controller though, I guess that's where I should start?